# How to organize columns of 2D array based on sum of columns?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I would like to organize a 2D array in descending order of each columns sum. For example:

```
3 1 1
2 6 5
5 4 2
```

The sum of column 1 would be 10, column 2 would be 11, column 3 would be 8. Columns 2 and 1 would need to switch to be sorted in descending order. The updated 2D array would be:

```
1 3 1
6 2 5
4 5 2
```

I'm aware of `Collections.reverseOrder()`, but that only works on sorting 1D arrays in descending order.

Here is the code I am using to get the sum of each column:

```java
int tempSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < columns; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
        tempSum = array[i][j]
    }
    //reset tempSum
    tempSum = 0;
}
```

I am currently not doing anything with the tempSum of each column. Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
int[][] transpose(int[][] matrix) {
    int rows = matrix.length, cols = matrix[0].length;
    int[][] transposed = new int[cols][rows];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; ++r)
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; ++c)
            transposed[c][r] = matrix[r][c];
    return transposed;
}
```

And

```
int[][] m = {
    {3, 1, 1, 9},
    {2, 6, 5, 4},
    {5, 4, 2, 6}};
m = transpose(m);
Arrays.sort(m, Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparingInt(row -> IntStream.of(row).sum())));
m = transpose(m);
for (int[] row : m)
    System.out.println("\t" + Arrays.toString(row));
```

output

```
[9, 1, 3, 1]
[4, 6, 2, 5]
[6, 4, 5, 2]
```

Or if you need more performance

```
m = transpose(m);
m = Arrays.stream(m)
    .map(row -> new Object() {
        int sum = IntStream.of(row).sum();
        int[] origin = row;
    })
    .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.compare(b.sum, a.sum))
    .map(obj -> obj.origin)
    .toArray(int[][]::new);
m = transpose(m);
```

Comment: Thank you, my actual problem requires the matrix to be flexible and this solution only works for 3x3. If I want to apply this to a 3x4 matrix, I get an index out of bound error.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Wow amazing. Cheers!